# Rails3 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:... no such table in every test

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I've started learning rails3 few days ago, and since today, every time I run unit test for my model I get this error message:

> `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: DELETE FROM "users" WHERE 1=1`

The tests went smoothly yesterday, I run them today (reverting everything to the state from the time they were working)... and I'm still getting the error.

I'm using rails 3 release on Windows7 64 bit, SQLite 3.7.2, ruby 187 (but I do have many ruby installations - using pik to select 187)

Any ideas on fixing this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It would be worth checking that your test database is set up correctly using the schema from your development database. You can achieve this with:

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

Comment: And don't forget `rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test` before that.

Answer (score 14):

If you created the model using a rails generator, you may have left over fixture files that are trying to access a table that isn't there anymore. For me, deleting the yml file solved the issue.

This was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6222934

Comment: Fixtures often get loaded into models; If a table no longer exists, you will get this error; Remove the fixtures that load into the non-existant table;

Comment: Yeah, or it may happen if you have renamed some models, and not renamed the fixture files as well.