# rake aborted! ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: Trouble Getting Rake Automation to Work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sqlite, whenever

I'm working on making a to-do list application and I'm trying to implement a feature where a to-do list item will automatically be deleted after 7 days if it never was completed within that time period.  I'm trying to use rake automation with the help of the 'whenever' gem however I receive the following error:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: items: SELECT "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE (created_at <= '2015-08-18 23:26:04.639414')
```

Here's the full stack trace:
https://gist.github.com/jlquaccia/0ac0eaa2b1d639fc514e

You can also view my most recent commit on Github [here](https://github.com/jlquaccia/Blocitoff)

I'm still a bit new to RoR and am confused by the error message because I already created a table named `items`.

db/migrate/20150817215220_create_items.rb:

```
class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :user, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Can someone please help?  I've been spinning my wheels on this one for a while today before I decided to ask here.

**UPDATE**

I have completely reset my db, re-migrated again in development and production and also recreated new users and items.  I know longer receive an error when running my rake automation (everything seems to have migrated smoothly this time).  However, my rake automation still does not work..

I went back and added a print statement inside of my rake task to help look deeper into things:

`puts Item.where("created_at <= ?", Time.now - 7.days).inspect`

When running this task manually I get:

input: `rake todo:delete_items`

output: `#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Item id: 2, name: "Milk", user_id: 1, created_at: "2015-08-24 18:16:25", updated_at: "2015-08-31 18:16:25">]>`

This proves that the rake task does work when run manually.

Yet when I go to automate this task:

schedule.rb:

```
every :day, :at => '12:09 pm' do
  rake "todo:delete_items"
end
```

Nothing happens, yet I do receive a message in the terminal.

```
Mail version 8.1 6/6/93.  Type ? for help.
"/var/mail/Jason": 1 message 1 new
>N  1 Jason@jason-quaccias  Mon Aug 31 12:09  19/900   "Cron <Jason@jason-quaccias-macbook-pro> /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/Jason/code/projects/blocitoff && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake todo:de"
? 
Message 1:
From Jason@jason-quaccias-macbook-pro.local  Mon Aug 31 12:09:18 2015
X-Original-To: Jason
Delivered-To: Jason@jason-quaccias-macbook-pro.local
From: Jason@jason-quaccias-macbook-pro.local (Cron Daemon)
To: Jason@jason-quaccias-macbook-pro.local
Subject: Cron <Jason@jason-quaccias-macbook-pro> /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/Jason/code/projects/blocitoff && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake todo:delete_items --silent'
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=Jason>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=Jason>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/Jason>
Date: Mon, 31 Aug 2015 12:09:15 -0700 (PDT)

#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Paying attention to the last line of the message `#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>` I can tell that my rake automation did run and printed out that it could not find a match for any items that are >= 7 days old.

However, this is not true.  Prior to automating my rake task I made sure there was an item that existed on production that was older than 7 days by running the Heroku rails console.

```
irb(main):003:0> u_items.find_by(id: 1)
=> #<Item id: 1, name: "Bread", user_id: 3, created_at: "2015-08-22 22:32:55", updated_at: "2015-08-30 22:32:55">
```

This is clear because the created_at attribute reads `"2015-08-22 22:32:55"`

However, this makes me wonder, has this bug now been reduced to some kind of configuration error?  Seems as though my rake task is running automatically yet it's not executing in the right place.  E.g. my rake task is not running in my production environment.

environment.rb:

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

todo.rake:

```
namespace :todo do
  desc "Delete items older than seven days"
  task delete_items: :environment do
    # Item.where("created_at <= ?", Time.now - 7.days).destroy_all
    puts Item.where("created_at <= ?", Time.now - 7.days).inspect
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you run `rake db:migrate` after creating migration file?

Comment: @Pavan I did run rake db:migrate after creating the file, still left me with the error above though..

Comment: You can go to your rails console and check: `Item.count` or `Item.first` to see if the `items` table exists in the database.

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam Thanks, I just went into my rails console to double check things (updated my question above to include my rails c code) and it looks like the table does exist, unclear why I'm still getting the error..

Comment: `RAILS_ENV=production` you ran the cron task in production environement. Did you check the production database if the items table is present there?

Comment: PS: One might come across this error if one has not renamed / deleted old fixture files. See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721564/rails3-activerecordstatementinvalid-no-such-table-in-every-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: items: SELECT "items".* FROM "items"
```

From the error message, it's obvious that the `items` table does not exist in your database right now. It got deleted somehow even if you did not delete it knowingly.

So, you should create the `items` table again by running the corresponding migration:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

#### Update

Check the `RAILS_ENV` in which you are running this rake task. As the error is showing up, this means you don't have the `items` table present in your database (looks like it's your production database). Then, you have to run the migration in that `RAILS_ENV` to create the `items` table back:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: I went ahead and reset my db both in development and production (see my comment on Michael Pell's answer above) and now I don't receive any errors at all when attempting to automate my rake task, however, it is still not working.  Maybe some sort of configuration issue, but I'm not sure..

Comment: If you did, `rake db:drop` then you lost all of your data in the database and you don't have anything in your `items` table. So,  the automate taks won't do anything. You need to create items in your `items` table to see your automate task in action.

Comment: I know, I did go back and create a new user and added a few new items under that user.  Then I went and updated the created_at attribute for one of the items so that it was created 8 days ago.  Yet when I readjust my rake automation to run again nothing happens and the item I updated is not deleted..  since it should be automatically deleted after 7 days.

Comment: did you make sure your rake task is being called? put a print statement inside and try to see if it finds the correct records to delete: `puts Item.where("created_at <= ?", Time.now - 7.days).inspect`

Comment: Thanks, I inserted a print statement into my rake task like you said to see if it is actually being called when automated.  It looks like it is because I do receive a message in the terminal that displays some printed output.  Yet my rake task is not running in the right place because the printed output returns an empty array when there should be an old item inside.  Note: I updated my question above (more details there).

Comment: right, this means your rake task is running but it can't find the items to delete in the database. make sure you are getting the data from the same database. Try to print: `puts Item.count` or ``puts Item.first` to see if they can print the record count to make sure your database really has some item data.

Comment: Ya the rake task is not running in the right db (I'm actually not sure where it's running because it does not work in development or production).  I ran the automated task with `puts Item.count` and the output I got was 0.  And items do in fact exist in development and production.

Comment: try to run the rake task like this: `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake todo:delete_items`, means, specifying the `RAILS_ENV`

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out.  Within my crontab I updated it to what you said and then also updated my schedule.rb file to `rake "todo:delete_items", :environment => 'development'`.  Now it runs fine in development!

Comment: awesome :) Consider accepting the answer if it helped to solve your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88512/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-jlquaccia).

Answer (score 1):

I am with the other commenters here and think that something funny has happened that might not be easy to understand.

My recommendation is to try running rake 'db:drop' and then 'rake db:migrate' just to make sure that things are the way that you think they are.

If the problem persists, I would expect it has something to do with rails environments. Are you setting the environment to anything other than 'development' anywhere?

if so, either dont do that, or, make sure you run 'RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate ' and probably read up on environments in the rails guides.

Comment: So I went back and ran `rake db:drop` then `rake db:migrate` to start fresh.  I also tried `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate` and even ran `heroku run rake db:migrate` and `heroku restart` to update production.  Now I don't receive any errors at all, but the automation is still not working.  Not working in development or production.  And as far as I can see I'm not setting the environment to anything other than development anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for the help!  To fix my rake automation to work in development, turns out I just had to log into my crontab via terminal with `crontab -e` and then edit my rails environment to `RAILS_ENV=development`.

Then since I am using the Whenever gem, within my schedule.rb file I had to set the environment to development there as well:

`rake "todo:delete_items", :environment => 'development'`

To get things to work on production, I use Heroku, all that I had to do was use the Heroku Scheduler add-on and I was able to get things working after a little bit of configuration setting.